# Zip compression in Channel image data from photoshop

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, photoshop, bit, psd

I have a problem with psd.js package from https://github.com/meltingice/psd.js I try to parse a .psd file on 16 and 32 bits but I was blocked on this issue https://github.com/meltingice/psd.js/issues/168 I fixed the problema but I still have one issue at parse compression.
For .psd file on 8 bits work perfectly, in this package don't exists a image parser for 16 or 32 bits, the function `parseZip` from channel_image.coffee it's not defined.

When the parseImageData function is executed the compression value is 2-3 in switch block but parseZip it's not defined and can't be executed.
[image]

Docs for type of compression: https://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/
[image]

I need some help to make a function `parseZip` which parse 16/32 bits images.

Comment: Hello Alex,
SO isn't a coding service and is the wrong place for this sort of question. You've already reached out on the GitHub repo, which is the proper channel, but it's not very active so you may not receive a solution soon.
If you badly need this update, I would suggest either finding a different plugin or hiring a developer to make the update via an online freelancing service.

Comment: Hi, it's enough to know what is zip compression in this case. I can't find more details about this compression.